# Where to store *.class servlets?

Tags: tomcat

I installed Centos 6.3 as a workstation. Both JDK and Tomcat 6 were installed as part of the included packages during the installation. Where should I place *.class files? What is the url I should use to access the servlet?

I have tried to search online but couldn't find a specific solution which added to the confusion from the book I'm reading.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

Comment: I tried to cd into /WEB-INF/ but it doesn't exist. What should I do? Also I tried to compile a simple servlet to test if I successfully got tomcat to work but I got javax.servlet doesn't exist.

Comment: It's up to YOU to create an appropriate directory layout containing a WEB-INF directory, which contains your classes in WEB-INF/classes, your jar dependencies in WEB-INF/lib, a web.xml descriptor in WEB-INF, and all your assets (html, css, images, JSPs, js, etc.) anywhere you likeunder the directory, and then to deploy this directory, as is or zipped in a war file, in Tomcat. IDEs do that for you, but it's quite simple to do it by yourself.